# Deleting columns from a data.frame where NA is more than 15% of the column length

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `data.frame` of 10 different columns (length of each column is the same). I want to eliminate any column that has '`NA`' greater than 15% of the column length.

Do I first need to make a function for calculating the percentage of `NA` for each column and then make another `data.frame` where I apply the function? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

First, it's always good to share some sample data. It doesn't need to be your actual data--something made up is fine.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(1000)
x[sample(1000, 150)] <- NA
mydf <- data.frame(matrix(x, ncol = 10))
```

Second, you can just use inbuilt functions to get what you need. Here, `is.na(mydf)` does a logical check and returns a `data.frame` of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Since `TRUE` and `FALSE` equate to `1` and `0`, we can just use `colMeans` to get the mean of the number of `TRUE` (is `NA`) values. That, in turn, can be checked according to your stipulations, in this case which columns have more than 15% `NA` values?

```
colMeans(is.na(mydf)) > .15
#    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As we can see, we should drop X1, X2, X6, X8, and X9. Again, taking advantage of logical vectors, here's how:

```
> final <- mydf[, colMeans(is.na(mydf)) <= .15]
> dim(final)
[1] 100   5
> names(final)
[1] "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X7"  "X10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with data.table like so

Load data into data.table. Call it DT. Say cols 2 through 4 are numeric.

```
Theta = 0.15
Drop <- DT[, lapply(.SD, function (x) {sum(is.na(x))/length(x) > Theta} ), .SDcols = 2:4]
Cols.2.Drop <- names(Drop)[which(Drop==TRUE)]
DT[, (Cols.2.Drop) := NULL]
```

Tested with data here:

```
Obs Var1    Var2    Var3
A0001   21  21  21
A0002   21  78  321
A0003   32  98  87
A0004   21  12  54
A0005   21  13  45
A0006   21  87  45
B0007   84  NA  45
B0008   21  NA  98
B0009   2   NA  45
B0010   12  NA  45
```