# R function to remove variables with more than 20% <NA> (*NOT* just ID them)?

Tags: r, function, na

I'm new to writing functions, am sure this is a simple one. I have a 111 col X ~10,500 row df with all missing values coded as `<NA>`. Intuitively, I need a function that does the following column-wise over a `dataframe`:

```
ifelse(length(is.na(colx) > length(colx)/5, NULL, colx)
```

i.e. I need to drop any variables with more than 1/5 (20%) missing values. Thanks to all for indicating there's a similar answer, i.e. using

```
colMeans(is.na(mydf)) > .20
```

to ID the columns, but this doesn't fully answer my question.

The above code returns a logical vector indicating the variables to be dropped. I have more than 100 variables with complex names and picking through them to drop by hand is tedious and bound to introduce errors. How can I modify the above, or use some version of my original proposed ifelse, to only return a new dataframe of columns with < 20% NA, as I asked originally?

Thanks!!

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821303/deleting-columns-from-a-data-frame-where-na-is-more-than-15-of-the-column-lengt

Comment: This should work: `mydf <- mydf[ , colMeans(is.na(mydf)) > 0.2 ]` , you can supply logical vector to choose columns to keep (TRUE) and to drop (FALSE).

Comment: @zx8754 thanks for this, works great! Also did find similar answer in the duplicate post: `final <- mydf[, colMeans(is.na(mydf)) <= .20]`

Comment: @jlev514 you can close as duplicate your own post.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this (probably not the shortest) is to iterate over the lines of the data.frame with `by` and then rbinding the result together to one data.frame.

Just change the condition in the if in the code below, here line with at least one `NA` value are removed.

```
do.call(rbind, by(your.dataset, 
              1:nrow(your.dataset), 
              FUN=function(x){
                if(sum(is.na(x))==0){ 
                    return(x) 
                  } else { 
                    return(NULL)} 
                }))
```

Comment: Is it one *column* per variable, or one *row*?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `lapply` on a `data.frame`, it performs the given function on each column as if each were a `list`.

So if `f` is your function for "processing" a column, you should use:

```
lapply(df, f)
```

`vapply` should be used when the result will always be a vector of a known size.

`sapply` is like an automatic `vapply`. It tries to simplify the result to a vector. I would [advise against using `sapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920286/effectively-debugging-shiny-apps), except for exploratory programming.

---

(Updated to reflect edit)

Try:

```
f <- function(x) {
    sum(is.na(x)) < length(x) * 0.2
}

df[, vapply(df, f, logical(1)), drop = F]
```

Comment: The question has been updated now, but the questioner was asking for a way to bind `x` in `function(x)` to a column. `lapply` does exactly that.